# Sync access for the same variable

Tags: go, concurrency, parallel-processing

I want to make sure that my update function is executed only by one thread at a time for a given value.

```
func update1(int id){
   ...
   makeUpdate(id)
   ...
}

func update2(int id){
   ...
   makeUpdate(id)
   ...
}
```

So, how should I write my makeUpdate() function that the myUpdate block is executed only once for a given id value? That means if update1 is updating the record with the id "15" and update2 with the id "20", the block access should not be synchronized.

Comment: That depends on what the records are and how they're held in memory - the body of `makeUpdate` is pretty important to answer this, but generally speaking in Go your primary synchronization tools are channels and `sync.Mutex`.

Comment: @Adrian thanks for the answer. However, i don't think the body should matter. The question is really how to synchronize depending on a value each caller has

Comment: The body matters very much, because `makeUpdate` is what needs to be synchronized, or more specifically, access to the data that `makeUpdate` is manipulating is what needs to be synchronized.

Comment: @Adrian no, it is not the access to the data that needs to be synched, it is the code in makeUpdate(). Imagine it just calls a service somewhere and we should treat it as a blackbox

Comment: Perhaps you could further explain your situation, because generally speaking, access to data is the only thing that ever needs to be synchronized.

Comment: You may find the [singleflight package](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sync/singleflight) useful.

Comment: @Sammy: Are the set of IDs unlimited or a fixed number? That will determine if you have to dynamically create mutexes.

Comment: Just to clarify - I think you are saying you want to serialize "updates" for the same ID but allow updates for different IDs to execute in parallel. You could use a sync.Mutex for each ID but a better way may be to create a channel for each ID and a go-routine for each channel that reads the ID and executes the update.

Answer (score 0):

As comments suggest - you need to protect data access not functional access.

Easiest way to achieve this, is to make a struct type with a lock - and attach the critical functional update as a method e.g.

```
type MyData struct {
        l sync.Mutex
        // add any other task related attributes here too
}

// makeUpdate *MUST* use a pointer to our struct (i.e. 'm *MyData')
// as Mutex logic breaks if copied (so no 'm MyData')
func (m *MyData) makeUpdate(id int) {
        m.l.Lock()
        defer m.l.Unlock()

        fmt.Printf("better makeUpdate(%d)\n", id) 

        // do critical stuff here

        // don't dilly-dally - lock is still being used - so return quickly
}
```

Try this out in the [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/yPtKtOsIXvw).